# How to identify read or write operations of page fault when using sigaction handler on SIGSEGV?(LINUX)

Tags: linux, page-fault

I use sigaction to handle page fault exception, and the handler function is defind like this:

```
void sigaction_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *_context)
```

So it's easy to get page fault address by reading **info->si_addr**.

The question is, how to know whether this operation is memory **READ** or **WRITE** ?

I found the type of **_context** parameter is **ucontext_t** defined in /usr/include/sys/[ucontext.h](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena.mit.edu/contrib/watchmaker/src/ofiles/h/ucontext.h)

There is a **cr2** field defined in mcontext_t, but unforunately, it is only avaliable when **x86_64** is not defind, thus I could not used cr2 to identify read/write operations.

On anotherway, there is a struct named **sigcontext** defined in /usr/include/bits/[sigcontext.h](http://repo-genesis3.cbi.utsa.edu/crossref/ns-sli/usr/include/bits/sigcontext.h.html)
This struct contains **cr2** field. But I don't know where to get it.

Answer (score 7):

You can check this in x86_64 by referring to the ucontext's mcontext struct and the err register:

```
void pf_sighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, ucontext_t *ctx) {
    ...
    if (ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ERR] & 0x2) {
        // Write fault
    } else {
        // Read fault
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the generation of SIGSEGV from the kernel `arch/x86/mm/fault.c`, `__bad_area_nosemaphore()` function:
http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L760

```
 760                tsk->thread.cr2         = address;
 761                tsk->thread.error_code  = error_code;
 762                tsk->thread.trap_nr     = X86_TRAP_PF;
 763
 764                force_sig_info_fault(SIGSEGV, si_code, address, tsk, 0);
```

There is `error_code` field, and it values are defined in `arch/x86/mm/fault.c` too:
http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L23

```
  23/*
  24 * Page fault error code bits:
  25 *
  26 *   bit 0 ==    0: no page found       1: protection fault
  27 *   bit 1 ==    0: read access         1: write access
  28 *   bit 2 ==    0: kernel-mode access  1: user-mode access
  29 *   bit 3 ==                           1: use of reserved bit detected
  30 *   bit 4 ==                           1: fault was an instruction fetch
  31 */
  32enum x86_pf_error_code {
  33
  34        PF_PROT         =               1 << 0,
  35        PF_WRITE        =               1 << 1,
  36        PF_USER         =               1 << 2,
  37        PF_RSVD         =               1 << 3,
  38        PF_INSTR        =               1 << 4,
  39};
```

So, exact information about access type is stored in the `thread_struct.error_code`: http://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux+v3.12/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L470

The `error_code` field is not exported into `siginfo_t` struct as I see (it is defined in
 http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html .. search for si_signo).

So you can

- Hack the kernel to export `tsk->thread.error_code` (or check, is it exported already or not, for example in `ptrace`)
- Get the memory address, read `/proc/self/maps`, parse them and check access bits on the page. If the page is present and read-only, the only possible fault is from writing, if page is not present both kinds of access are possible, and if... there should be no write-only pages.
- Also you can try to find the address of failed instruction, read it and disassemble.

Comment: The error_code information can be accessed through:
  ((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ERR].
It is passed by the hardware on the stack, which is then passed to the signal handler by the kernel, since the kernel passes the entire `frame'.

Comment: M. Alaggan, which hardware?

Answer (score 5):

The error_code information can be accessed through:

```
err = ((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_ERR]
```

It is passed by the hardware on the stack, which is then passed to the signal handler by the kernel, since the kernel passes the entire `frame'. Then

```
bool write_fault = !(err & 0x2);
```

will be true if the access was a write access, and false otherwise.